# Why does this slice produce no output?

Tags: python-3.x, slice

This is my input format:

```
C234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
CBD05-001-03         1001131452.60S1274819.69E 370584.88535135.6  74.8     
CBD05-001-03         1002131451.92S1274819.24E 370571.28535156.4  74.8
```

I want to slice into different strings based on fixed column ranges.   This works fine if the column ranges start before the spaces in columns 12 to 20, but if the slice only contains spaces then I get no output at all.  Can anyone explain why this is happening?

e.g.  If I use this code

```
print (line[22:5])
print (line[0:30])
```

only the 0:30 slice prints:

```
C23456789012345678901234567890

CBD05-001-03         100113145

CBD05-001-03         100213145
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question. line[22:5] will not print anything because it is an invalid slice. If you want to print 5 characters starting from 22, you should do: line[22:27].

Comment: Thanks, I think you did understand the question - it's me who didn't understand the syntax.  I assumed the slicing worked like BASIC where you specify the starting character and then he number of characters, instead of the starting and ending characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(line[22:5])
```

Prints the characters from character 22 up to but not including character 5.
Since character 5 is before character 22, it will print nothing.